# GIDSignIn Auth in Keychain not saved

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, keychain, google-signin

I'm developing an iOS Swift application which enables Google Sing In and [Google App Invite](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/). To do that I'm using GoogleSignIn v2.2.0 as follow :

```
func loginRequest(onSuccess successBlock: () -> Void, onError errorBlock: (String?) -> Void) {

    var signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
    signIn.allowsSignInWithWebView = false
    signIn.allowsSignInWithBrowser = true
    signIn.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]
    signIn.delegate = self

    if  signIn.hasAuthInKeychain(){
        signIn.signInSilently()
    }else{
        signIn.signIn()
    }

}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
       // managing login data here            
        self.successBlock()
    } else {
        self.errorBlock(error.localizedDescription)
    }    
}
```

Till here everything is working as expected and I'm able to successfully sign in. What I need next, as described above, is to use Google App Invite which require signing in first so I need user to stay logged in and thats the reason why I never call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`. If I invoke my invite method just after signing in it will open the invite dialog as expected but the problem I'm facing with occur only after my app is restarted and when `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()` returns always false. So my question is : Is it possible to keep auth in keychain after app is released from memory and use it later. If not what really makes me confused is `signInSilently()`method which looks totally pointless

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. However, I found the point about Google Sign-In.
I wrote `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];` and `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];`in different original method,

For example,

```
- (void)checkOAuth {
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
    if([GIDSignIn sharedInstance].hasAuthInKeychain) {
         GIDGoogleUser *user = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser;
         if(!user) {
             [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
         }
    }
}

- (void)didReceivedLogin {

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = @[@https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"];
    // Google SignInを実行
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];

}
```

However, I could get true from hasAuthInKeychain by fixing code.
First, I changed to write GIDSignIn's new method in ViewDidLoad method.
It unified the status about GIDSignIn in my Application.

I hope this will help you.